# Could not use patgen

Tags: hyphenation, patgen

All I see on my console is "Bad Representation" for even the .TRA file example of the patgen2 manual itself. What should I do?

Comment: That was just about no information at all. Provide a some more information.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: What kind of information? For an empty .TRA it works, but it is not enough for me, I need a .TRA file.

Comment: I tried the example from the manual, but it does not work.

Comment: Do someone actually use patgen for something?

Comment: Please respond.

Comment: @Svend Mortensen What more information do you want?

Comment: @antonio I’m sorry you apparently didn’t to get a satisfactory response. Unfortunately, I can’t help you with this problem, but if you go to our [chat], the friendly folks there will be able to assist you in improving your question. Afterwards, we can reopen it.